# jstree question

Tags: jquery, jstree

I am using XML as my datasource for my JSTree tree, but I cannot find any examples where you can set a node in your XML as a hyperlink, or anywhere to set your own node types with their own icon etc.  Has anybody done this and have examples?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the [jsTree Types plugin documentation](http://www.jstree.com/documentation/types).

Comment: It doesn't have the type of example I am looking for.  I want to know how to make one of my xml nodes a hyperlink.

Comment: @user: what do you mean by that? A link in the browser itself?

Comment: Yes, a node that when clicked will redirect to another page.

Comment: @user: I don't think that's a standard use case for jsTree. You'd probably have to hack this functionality in yourself.

Comment: Strange..I would've thought using such a tree to navigate to for example different documents or webpages would be one of it's main uses.

Comment: @user: I don't find it strange. If you navigate away from the page containing the tree, you'd lose _at least_ the tree's state (what's expanded, for instance). I do not think that jsTree is a suitable nav menu component. At any rate, if you want to implement this yourself, [this thread](http://www.devcomments.com/jsTree-2902-Link-not-working-at68427.htm) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for jsTree states:

> All attributes you set on the item node will be transfered to the resulting *li* node. All attributes you set on the name node will be transfered to the resulting *a* node.

By default, jsTree adds an href address of the current page to the anchor tag generated from the *name* node in the XML markup (flat or nest).  You can override the href with your own address.  Here's an example:

```
<item id="link__1" parent_id="0">
  <content>
    <name title="Click here to go to website" href="http://google.com">Google</name>
  </content>
</item>
```

Another option is to use jQuery to capture the click event on the *a* tag and redirect based on the text node or something.  In that case, use a delegate on a container (diagMenu in the following example) for the jsTree to monitor the clicks.

```
$("#diagMenu").delegate('a', 'click', function(e) {
                         //code to redirect based on event object
                       });
```

Kind of a late response but hopefully this is a help to you or others that stumble across this answer.

Answer (score 1):

jstree Nodes render as hyperlinks ("a" or "anchor" tags) as long as you are set up right. You can bind some javascript to the node select event like this:

```
jQuery(".foldertree").bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    // use this to debug: alert("data.rslt.name=" + data.rslt.name + " data.rslt.obj.attr('rel')=" + data.rslt.obj.attr("rel"));

    // to get selected node Id and type
    var nodeId = data.rslt.obj.attr("id");
    var nodeType = data.rslt.obj.attr("rel");

    // to get node's immediate parent node
    parentId = data.rslt.obj[0].parentNode.parentNode.id;

    // use this info to call a method or go to another page
    window.location = "somepage.aspx?" + nodeId;
}
```

Here is how I set different node types with different icons. My tree represents documents in folders, so I have "default" (Folders), and "form" (Documents) types:

```
jQuery(".foldertree")

.jstree({
```

.
.                        *(various setup stuff)*
.

```
"types": {
    // -2 means don't check (faster)
    "max_depth": -2,
    "max_children": -2,
    // This will prevent moving or creating any other type as a root node
    "valid_children": ["default"],
    "types": {

        // Folders
        "default": {
            // can have files and other folders inside of it
            "valid_children": ["default", "form"],
            "icon": {
                    "image": "css/jstree/folder.png"
            }
        },

        // Documents (saved forms). 
        "form": {
            // No children (so only leaf nodes)
            "valid_children": "none",
            // override theme icon
            "icon": {
                    "image": "css/jstree/file.png"
            }
        },


    } // end types (within types)
}, // end types (outer)

"themes":
```

.
.  *(etc)*
.